# Unable to add custom color in vuetify project

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify and I was following https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/theme/#custom-theme-variants for adding a custom theme color. I tried to do this in my theme.js file

```
// src/plugins/vuetify/theme.js

import colors from 'vuetify/lib/util/colors'

export default {
    // All keys will generate theme styles,
    // Here we add a custom `name` color
    name: colors.pink,
}
```

But when I included it in my project, it isn't working.

```
    <v-app-bar app color="name" dark dense elevation="1">
```

What could be wrong here? Can someone help please?
Here is my project structure

[image: Project structure]

Comment: You should apply your new theme as described in https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/tree/master/packages/docs/src/snippets/js/theme_file_import.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that:

```js
// src/plugins/vuetify.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        custom: '#05a334',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

```js
// src/main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './app.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <div>
      <v-btn color="custom">Test</v-btn>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
};
</script>
```